# Usage of anonymous arrays in C without "expected ';' before '}' token"

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I try to use some "anonymous arrays" (not sure of the name) in a conditional block. I have the following code

```
if (({10, 20, 30})[0] == 10) {
```

I compile with GCC 4.6.1 in Windows (MSys) and compilation options `-Wall -I/usr/include -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter`. It is raising the following warnings and errors

```
my_code.c:1:9: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
my_code.c:1:13: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
my_code.c:1:17: error: expected ';' before '}' token
```

If I define the array outside it is working perfectly:

```
int anonymous_array_01[3] = {10, 20, 30};
if (anonymous_array_01[0] == 10) {
```

What is going wrong (potentially an error related to GCC version or compilation options)?

Thanks

Comment: That's not an anonymous array, that's a syntax error (or GCC's [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) extension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of literal `{ 10, 20, 30 }`? Is it an array literal of type `int[3]`, `double[3]`, `long[3]`, `char[3]` or even a struct literal (if so, which struct type?) The compiler requires type information that you have not provided, hence the compilation error.

The fix is to include type information, creating a well-formed compound literal, which is the set of values you have, plus a cast expression:

```
(int[]){10, 20, 30}
```

You can do the same with a struct:

```
(struct{int x,y,z;}){10, 20, 30}
```

Answer (score 3):

This construction

```
{10, 20, 30}[0]
```

does not make sense.

Instead use a compound literal

```
if ( ( int [] ){10, 20, 30}[0] == 10)
```

Answer (score -1):

This

```
if (({10, 20, 30})[0] == 10) {
```

makes no sense.

It is nothing but an wrong way of declaring an array.

it is probably because

```
{10,20,30,}
```

does not invoke an array. If you want to compare it, you must use traditional array.